# Why does python keep complaining that my constructor is sent one too few arguments?

Tags: python, constructor

I have the following class:

```
class Gene(object):

    """
    Represents transcripts.

    Called gene for convenience, but the class actually represents different transcripts of genes.
    """
    def _set_start_end(strand, start_position, end_position):

        if strand == '-':
            return end_position, start_position
        else:
            return start_position, end_position

    def __init__(self, transcript_name, gene_name, chromosome, strand, start_position, end_position):
        self.transcript_name = transcript_name
        self.gene_name = gene_name
        self.chromosome = chromosome
        self.strand = strand
        self.start_position, self.end_position = _get_start_end(strand, start_position, end_position)
```

When I try to instantiate this class with `refgene = Gene("NM_016166", "PIAS1", "Chr15", "-" "68346571", "68480404")`, Python keeps complaining that I have one argument too few:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
refgene = Gene("NM_016166", "PIAS1", "Chr15", "-" "68346571", "68480404")
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 7 arguments (6 given)
```

Why? I am surely not mean to send self to the constructor?

Ps. `Python 2.7.8 :: Anaconda 2.0.0 (64-bit)`

Comment: You're missing a comma after "-"

Comment: I am a moron. Please add that as a real answer and I'll upvote plus accept it. (Creating a pillory for myself).

Comment: I think Martijn's answer has it covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed a comma:

```
Gene("NM_016166", "PIAS1", "Chr15", "-" "68346571", "68480404"),
#                                      ^
```

Making that **one** string as Python concatenates two strings separated only by whitespace:

```
>>> 'foo' 'bar'
'foobar'
```

Add in the comma:

```
Gene("NM_016166", "PIAS1", "Chr15", "-", "68346571", "68480404"),
```

Next problem is that your `_set_start_end` function is not going to work; you either need to make it a method, or move it *out* of the class. If it is a method, you need to add `self` in two places; one to call it and one to receive the bound instance:

```
self.start_position, self.end_position = self._get_start_end(strand, start_position, end_position)
```

and:

```
def _set_start_end(self, strand, start_position, end_position):
```

Comment: True but not actually the problem here. Jason spotted the real one in his comment.

Comment: It's also not calling self._get_start_end, not sure if the intent there is to have a self or have it be static.

Comment: Didn't forget; I've just never used the OO capabilities of Python before.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I indeed was speed-reading the wrong part and spotted that first..

Comment: @TheUnfunCat: You had multiple problems; I'll scan for more.